# Live Preview function in Multilingual Craft CMS website

Tags: craftcms

Struggling a bit with a multilingual Craft CMS website. I am trying to get Live Preview working on both languages I use on my site. The Primary language works just fine, live preview is showing, and all edits are visible. However, if I switch to the secondary language and try to preview I get thre primary version.

In my .env file I setup two environmental variables the following URL's which I use in "Settings > Sites > Base URL":

```
PRIMARY_SITE_URL=http://mysite.local:8080
PRIMARY_SITE_URL_EN=http://mysite.local:8080/en/
```

In my Sections settings, I configured it as shown below:

[image]

I tried changing the second row in "Preview Targets" to `en/news/{slug}` however this was without success.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Brandon Kelly from Craft:

```
Just a single preview target should be necessary, with its URL Format set to {url}. It will show the entry in whichever site is currently being edited.
```

This solved the problem right away for me.

Thanks Brandon